# Create a Tuple of 4 Int32 elements

Tags: julia

I want to create a tuple which holds four Int32 values.

If I simply do:

```
julia> a = (2,3,4,5)
(2, 3, 4, 5)

julia> typeof(a)
NTuple{4,Int64}
```

I get a four elements Tuple of Int64, what shall be done in Julia to get an Int32 NTuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are running a 64 bit version of julia,
your integer literals default to Int64.

To get a tuple of `Int32` you need to to pass in Int32.

#### Either by constructing them as `Int32` before you build the tuple

```
julia> x = (Int32(1), Int32(2), Int32(3), Int32(4))
(1, 2, 3, 4)

julia> typeof(x)
NTuple{4,Int32}
```

#### Converting each element of the tuple

```
julia> y = convert.(Int32, (1,2,3,4))
(1, 2, 3, 4)

julia> typeof(y)
NTuple{4,Int32}
```

#### Converting the whole tuple

```
julia> z = convert(NTuple{4, Int32}, (1,2,3,4))
(1, 2, 3, 4)

julia> typeof(z)
NTuple{4,Int32}
```

#### or the NTuple constructor.

This one always catchs me out as it takes a tuple,
not the elements, so count your brackets,

```
julia> a = NTuple{4,Int32}((1,2,3,4))
(1, 2, 3, 4)

julia> typeof(a)
NTuple{4,Int32}
```

Comment: Another possibility is `NTuple{4, Int32}((1, 2, 3, 4))`.  Given an arbitrary length input tuple `t`, you could also do `NTuple{length(T), Int32}(t)`.

Comment: @AnshulSinghvi added

Answer (score 4):

Since you expect your function to return a tuple of `Int32`s, I assume that this is also what your function is using internally. Therefore there should presumably be no need to do any conversion (why else do you want to return `Int32`s?) If you are on a 32-bit system, you could simply use `Int` since that is equal to `Int32` on 32-bit systems, and `Int64` on 64-bit systems.

But if you actually still need to do a conversion, this is much more convenient, and just as fast as `convert`:

```
julia> a = (1, 2, 3, 4)

julia> b = Int32.(a)
```

Comment: Thanks that it is also easier to follow. I am on a 64-bits system, but operating huge integer arrays. I want to use 32 bits to save some memory as 32 bits are enough for the data I manage.

Comment: That makes sense for large arrays, but not for length 4 tuples. Can't you convert them whenever they need to go into the large arrays? I'm thinking, make it simple and native, and then convert when necessary.

Comment: If the data is 32 bits I prefer to have all functions/routines handling that to be 32 bits. It seems a bit cleaner. I am probably trying to mimic C where data is strongly typed.

Comment: But in that case, shouldn't your functions be using `Int32`s for all calculations? Why do you need the conversion in that case?

Comment: I have seen that defining the individual variables which conform the Tuple as `Int32`, `a::Int32=0`, `b::Int32=0`, `c::Int32=0`, `d::Int32=0`, and then conforming the Tuple as `(a, b, c, d)` also generates an `Int32` Tuple (and forces everything to use 32 bits from the beginning). So as you say I finally do not need conversion. That does not imply that I do not want to understand how conversion works (I have been working with Julia for just a couple of days so even basic concepts are new to me).

Comment: Sure. Generally, for conversions you can try `T(x)` for scalars, and `T.(x)` for collections. It may not always work, but when it does, it's very convenient.

Comment: @mug896 This will be _much_ slower than `Int32.((1,2,3))`. What is the advantage of your approach?

Comment: @DNF your approach is the best in speed. this is the same `b = Int32.((1:4...,))`